# Vimium for Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I like to use Vimium all the time, but I'm having some difficulty understanding how to use it for Google Docs. In Google Docs, I can't seem to stop the cursor from blinking (i.e. it's as though I'm perpetually in insert mode - no matter how many times I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>). This means that, when I go to issue a command to Vimium, I end up merely typing the command verbatim into the Google Doc.
I've googled around online with no success. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically can't.  Google Docs is super zealous about dropping you back into insert mode (as you observed).  Best just disable Vimium on Google Docs (`https?://docs.google.com/document/*`).

Comment: I had a rule to disable Vimium on `https?://docs.google.com/*` but just today all of a sudden the Vimium keys kicked in again. Clicking the Vimium icon revealed that the active window URL of my Google Docs tab was `about:blank*`, so I added a rule to disable Vimium on that URL as well and now Google Docs is OK again. I wonder if it's my PC or Google that's causing this change of behaviour.

Comment: @vicmortelmans can confirm I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 5):

In order to use Vimium shortcuts the focus of the page can't be on the cursor.
What I do is move the page focus to the menu using Google Docs' own shortcuts.
Using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> the 'File' menu opens and focus goes there, enabling me to use Vimium.

Before I discovered this I used Chrome shortcuts to go to another tab and continued there (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>)

There is 1 option I know of to get back and edit the page (other than clicking it). Here is how it goes:

1. use Vimium command **f** to follow links
2. choose editing scroll menu on the top right (editing/suggesting/viewing)
3. choose editing with arrows and enter key

Thy idea behind this method is to use the Google Docs menu in order to get back to editing.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion works to get out of the trap. It's ```ctrl + opt + f``` on Mac to get the 'File' menu.
Also, pressing ```Esc``` works to get back into "Insertion" mode.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible for Chrome extensions to interact with Google Docs editors, instead you could try to use Google Apps Script or Google Docs editors add-ons.

It's worth to say that Google Apps Script/Google Docs editors doesn't include event listeners for keyboard combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vimium with google docs!

press "esc" and "f" at the same time and you'll get all the vimium option to pop up and overlay the screen/browser.